# Log4J: AsyncAppender and NullPointerException during stacktrace print

Tags: log4j, nullpointerexception, appender

Updated:
This is true not only for AsyncAppender. Happens for console one as well.

I faced with wierd behavior of AsyncAppender that occurs rarely but with sufficient harm.

Here is code snippet:

```
public void testNPE() {
    try {
        try {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        logger.error("Catcha!" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Probable result should be:

```
07.12.12 10:21:34,904 ERROR [main] >> [com.ubs.eqdel.markitfeed.core.RetrieverTest:74]          Catcha! java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ubs.eqdel.markitfeed.core.RetrieverTest.testNPE(RetrieverTest.java:71)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ubs.eqdel.markitfeed.core.RetrieverTest.testNPE(RetrieverTest.java:69)
    ... 25 more
```

But for 5 of 20 attempts I see:

```
Exception in thread "Dispatcher-Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter.write(CountingQuietWriter.java:45)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:309)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:263)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:160)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender$Dispatcher.run(AsyncAppender.java:583)
    at java.lang.T07.12.12 10:23:54,972 ERROR [main] >> [com.ubs.eqdel.markitfeed.core.RetrieverTest:74]  Catcha! java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ubs.eqdel.markitfeed.core.RetrieverTest.testNPE(RetrieverTest.java:71)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ubs.eqdel.markitfeed.core.RetrieverTest.testNPE(RetrieverTest.java:69)
    ... 25 more
```

What's wrong with AsyncAppender? Did anybody face the same? And what is the workaround on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44032).

Edit: Based on the [release notes](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/changes-report.html#a1.2.16), 1.2.16 (released on 2010-04-06) should contain [the fix for this](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=612863).

Comment: Yeah, definitely. I checked with sources. Thank you for spotting the ticket. Looks like version 27 has this issue fixed at least I haven't faced with it yet.

Comment: Great. I guess you meant 17, and not 27.

Comment: Exactly! The 17th one. Sorry for my fat fingers.